# Change hovered card background color using sass

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I need background color `lightgreen` on card hover.

```
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" 
alt="card-theme"/>
      <div class="hovered-text">
        Open
      </div>
    </div>
```

styles

```
.card {
  background: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  .hovered-text {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    color: salmon;
  }
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    opacity: 1;
    &:hover {
     opacity: 0.1;
     background: lightgreen;
    }
    &:hover~.hovered-text{
      display: block
    }
  }
}
```

Code in [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hover-card-48ihr?file=/src/styles.scss)

Please help to make it work. Thanks

Comment: `&:hover {` on `.card` not working ....or ? because i see you use it on `img` so you know about it

Comment: @MihaiT tried but not working

Comment: well it seems to BE working. https://codesandbox.io/s/hover-card-forked-wtihx?file=/src/styles.scss . If in your project it's not working then you probably have a typo or an unclosed `{}` or something that overwrites your hover styles. Please do further debugging

Comment: well. what was the problem the first time ? because you said it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is add hover to the class card. Eg:

```
.card {
  &:hover {
    background: lightgreen;
   }
```

Example:

```
card {
  background: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
&:hover {
        background: lightgreen;
       }
  .hovered-text {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    color: salmon;
  }
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    opacity: 1;
    &:hover {
     opacity: 0.1;
     background: lightgreen;
    }
    &:hover~.hovered-text{
      display: block
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your .card backgroundcolor to lightgreen

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.card {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  .hovered-text {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    color: salmon;
  }
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    opacity: 1;
    &:hover, ::after {
     opacity: 0.3;
    //  background: #lightgreen;
    }
    &:hover~.hovered-text{
      display: block;
      
    }
  }
}
```

Code in [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hover-card-forked-wn55e?file=/src/styles.scss)